# Invoice PDF print Arabic Character?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I am having problem in Printing invoice when the costumer time Arabic Character in checkout. The Arabic word is become square charcter.

Anyone knows possible alternative on this ?

Answer (score 0):

language Package : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-arabic-saudi-arabia-language-pack.html get key

Admin panel ->system-> Magento Connect install new language package

admin panel-> system-> Configuration -chose you Current Configuration Scope -General -> Locale Options set :Locale Arabic (Saudi Arabia) or your arabic package you chose (Egypt , Morocco ..etc)

admin panel -> system -> Cache Management : Flush Magento Cache

visit bellow link:

refresh front page for your store

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029844/installing-arabic-language-for-magento